# Cannot Retrieve new messages with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, chat

Im working on chat application and I'm trying to retrieve messages from database using Ajax and `setInterval` function to get new message inserted and then append it to the chat box.

NB. The chat app is similar to Facebook chat. chat between two users only.

The problem is the chatbox keep refreshing and displaying random messages from both users. and i don't know why???

Here is code:
 The chat link is like this:
    message.php?receiver=username

**Database stucture:**

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `forum_inbox` (
   `id_msg` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `sender_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `receiver_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `message` text NOT NULL,
   `dateMsg` int(11) NOT NULL,
   `seen` enum('no','yes') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
   `date_seen` int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id_msg`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

**messages.php**

```
$sender_id   = $_SESSION['id_userf'];
$receiver_id = get_username_id($_GET['receiver']);
$stmt = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM `forum_inbox`  
                       WHERE 
                           (sender_id=? AND receiver_id=?) 
                       OR 
                           (sender_id=? AND receiver_id=?) 
                       ORDER BY dateMsg ASC");

$stmt->execute(array($sender_id, $receiver_id, $receiver_id, $sender_id));    
$messages = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

<div id="inbox-chat">
    <section class="chat-container">
        <ol class="chat-box" id="chat-box">                
            <?php  foreach($messages AS $msg):  ?> 
                <li data-messageid="<?php echo $msg->id_msg ?>">
                    <div class="messages">
                        <p><?php echo $msg->message ?></p>
                        <time datetime="time_stamp($msg->dateMsg);?>">
                            <?php echo time_stamp($msg->dateMsg);?>
                            <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 
                            <?php echo $msg->dateMsg; ?>
                        </time>
                    </div>
                </li>               
            <?php endforeach; ?> 
          </ol>
    </section>
</div>
```

**tchat.js**

```
timer = setInterval(newestMessages, 2000); 
function newestMessages() {
/************************************************/ 
/* ***receiver*** value is passed from a hidden input /
/**********************************************/ 
    var receiver    = $(".receiver").val();         
    var newest_msg  = $('.chat-box').children('li').last().data("messageid");
    $.ajax({
        url : 'ajax/inbox.php',
        data : 'receiver='+receiver +'&newest_msg='+newest_msg ,

        success : function(data){   
            $("#chat-box").append(data);
            $('#chat-box').slimscroll({ scrollBy: '450px' }); 
        }
    });
}
```

**inbox.php**

```
ob_start();
session_start();
require_once '../../config/connect.php';
require_once '../../functions/func.php'; 

$sender_id = $_SESSION['id_userf'];
$receiver_id = $_GET['receiver']; 
$last_msg = $_GET['newest_msg'];

    $stmt = $PDO->prepare("SELECT * FROM `forum_inbox` 
        WHERE 
            (sender_id=? AND receiver_id=?) 
        OR 
            (sender_id=? AND receiver_id=?) 
        AND 
            id_msg > ?
        ORDER BY dateMsg ASC
    ");

$stmt->execute(array($sender_id,$receiver_id,$receiver_id,$sender_id,$last_msg));    
    $messages = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0): 
        foreach($messages AS $msg):                 
            echo '<li data-messageid="'.$msg->id_msg.'">
                    <div class="messages">
                    <p>'.$msg->message.'</p>
                    <time datetime="'.$msg->dateMsg.'">

                        <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                        '.$msg->dateMsg.'
                    </time>
                </div>
            </li>';             
            endforeach; 
    endif;
```

Comment: You may want to filter your messages.php `Select` statement to only pull `seen = 'no'` and afterwards, update it to 'yes'. This will help to only fetch new messages.

Comment: and what's the problem with query I made? 
Theorically it must work, no?

Comment: I triied your method, but same problem, i think there is something wrong with newestMessages() function i made !!

Comment: It works, it's just pulling everything. That's what I would assume the `seen` flag is there for, correct?

Comment: yeah, but trying to pull message which are not seen yet give me the same problem, the setInterval function keep pulling messages randomly and it took me 2 days and still couldn't figure out where is the problem !!